# Convert List<List<String>> to List<List<num>> in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-api

I would like to check a coordinate with in polygon (Google map). From my REST API, the polygon coordinates datatype was in `List<List<String>>`. I am using a specific package to check within polygon a package named `poly` which accept  `List<List<num>>` datatype. To convert `List<List<String>>` to `List<List<num>>` for google map api in flutter, how should I do that?

Comment: Can you include more details ,  what are you trying to archive, and what have you tried so far? I don't understand your question `List<List> to List<List>`?